# Changing inherited function to be pure virtual

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual

I'm wondering if the following is possible. I wanted my derived class `dA` to change `func()` to be pure virtual so that any classes derived from `dA` must implement `func()`.

<s>Code similar to below compiles without complaint under MSVC even though `ddA` does not implement `func()`.</s>

The compiler does complain about the below code (see comments). So my question now becomes: is this a standards-compliant way to achieve what I want?

```
class A {
   public:
      virtual void func() { /* Some base implementation. */ }
}

class dA : public A {
   public:
      void func() override = 0;   // Is this valid?
}

class ddA : public dA {
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete virtual function from a derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609872/delete-virtual-function-from-a-derived-class)

Comment: _Code similar to below compiles without complaint under MSVC even though `ddA` does not implement `func()`._ Have you tried to make an instance of `ddA`. I tried to reproduce in g++. Your example compiled without complaints. This changed as soon as I added an `ddA obj;` because now it's a problem. (Abstract classes may not be instanced and `ddA` is such if `func()` is not overridden and defined.) [Test on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/749fb263e1b26557)

Comment: Beside of this, I already have used derived classes which make an overridden function pure virtual even although a base class has it implemented. I did this explicitly to make intermediate classes non-instance-able. AFAIK, there is nothing wrong with this and I never noticed any unexpected behavior of the compiler concerning this. (I'm using VS2019, and have done so with VS2013, VS2008.)

Comment: @Scheff you're right, it behaves as I expect if I add `ddA obj`. I forgot that in the case of my class, it only gets instantiated via scripting at runtime (via a meta object system), so the compiler wasn't aware of the instantiation. Updated the question.

Comment: IMHO, this doesn't change anything. Even a meta-system has to `new` the instance somewhere. Either this will complain about the incomplete class or (if it is achieved with a hacky trick) you just will run into a crash when something tries to call the `nullptr` for the pure virtual function from v-table. (I once managed this already somehow although I don't remember anymore how I did this achieve, and it was clearly my fault in this case...)

Comment: When I first posted the question I hadn't run the code, I'd only compiled it. Indeed the meta-object system throws a runtime error that it cannot instantiate the class. But the compiler wasn't aware. I'm using Qt's QML runtime type registration APIs (qmlRegisterType<T>() and friends). I suspect that if I instead used the QML_ELEMENT macro to register the types then I would get errors at compile-time. But I'm using cmake and unfortunately this macro only works with qmake.

Answer (score 1):

`Pure virtual` function should be declared in parent class. Consider the code below:
'''

```
class Shape {
public:
    Shape(int init_x, int init_y) : x(init_x), y(init_y) {}

    virtual void scale(int s) = 0;
    virtual void print() = 0;
protected:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

These functions should be implemented in children:

```
class Rect : public Shape {
public:
    Rect(int init_x, int init_y, int w, int h);
    virtual void scale(int s) { //implementation }
    virtual void print() { //implementation }
private:
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

However you don't have to implement virtual functions in subclasses since it had been implemented in super class:

Pure virtual function make your class abstract so you can't use its instances.