# Visibility of private virtual function in abstract base classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer, virtual-functions

Consider following code:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void f() const = 0;
  void callf() const { f(); }
};

class B : public A {
  virtual void f() const { }
};

int main()
{
  B x;
  x.callf();

  return 0;
}
```

Class `B` derives from the abstract base class `A`, but "hides" the implemented method `f()` as private member.
Still, the inherited member `callf()` is able to call `f()`, which was public in the base class.
The code compiles with no warning on g++ 10.1.0 and clang++ 11.1.0.

Is this a legal code, i.e., does the inherited `callf()` correctly see the private member `f()`?

Alternatively, would it be possible for the derived class `B` to implement the purely virtual methods of the base class, such that they can only be called by `B` (and friends)?

Comment: You want a function of derived class not allowed to be called by base? Isn't it breaking Liskov Substitution Principle?

Comment: Not sure what your last sentence/question means. In the code you show, the derived class `B` **does** implement the pure virtual method of the base class.

Comment: My suggestion is enforcing the base class fully abstract (deleted), so behavior is defined by derived classes.

Comment: @LouisGo yes, I would like the base class methods to not be able to call f().

Comment: Then how does `B::f()` knows whether it's called by base or derived class? Or you want compiler error when `B::f()` is called?

Comment: If you just wants no one uses `B::f()`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24610165/4123703) might help.

Comment: Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24609999/4123703) for the same question might help as well.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is this a legal code, i.e., does the inherited callf() correctly see the private member f()?*

Yes, it is legal code. From the compiler's point-of-view, the `callf` function is referencing the `f` function of *its own* class; the fact that that is a virtual function does not affect the scope (or accessibility) – only the implementation, which will be in the form of a call to a v-table entry. That v-table entry will be correctly interpreted at run time, when it is called *via* the derived class.